# AltGr in System.Windows.Forms.Keys enumerator

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Should be an easy one.  What is the value of the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key in the System.Windows.Forms.Keys enumerator?

I've looked through it and can't see anything obvious ('AltrGr' no, 'RAlt' no, 'GrAlt' no).

**Updated - Answered:**

```
if (ModifierKeys == ( Keys.Control | Keys.Alt ) )
{
    // AltGr is held down
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my minimal research on Google, in Windows you can substitue Ctrl + Alt to get the equivalent of the AltGr key.  I don't think new keyboards have that key anymore.

Chris

Comment: This has nothing to do with old or new keyboards; it is some *keyboard layouts*, e.g. the [German one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_keyboard_layout), that feature an *Alt Gr* key replacing one of the two *Alt* keys.

Comment: What Taran and O. R. Mapper say is correct. This answer should not be marked as the correct one.

Answer (score 4):

Most keyboards **do** still include this key.

You're looking for `RMenu`.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys) description:

> The right ALT key.